# Show posts of each month one after the other with a calendar on the side

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to achieve what's inside the image:

[image: Goal]

What I have at the moment is:

[image: Currently]

I'm practically done but what I'm not able to figure out is how to make the posts of same month fill inside the `col-10` div while when we get to a new set of posts with a different month, the `<div class='tax-calendar-container container'><div class='row'>` div should be introduced again so that each month ends up in a different container so that they stack properly.

It's working when there's only one post per month but when there is 2 or more, the first shows where it should but the rest show alone on a row.

Any idea what logic should I add to make the intended changes?

```
function taxCalendar()
{

    $current_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    $count = 0;
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    if(get_locale() == 'en_US') {
        $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post', 'category_name' => 'Tax Calendar', 'post_status' => 'future', 'posts_per_page' => 6, 'paged' => $paged));
    } else {
        $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post', 'category_name' => 'Tax Calendar AR', 'post_status' => 'future', 'posts_per_page' => 6, 'paged' => $paged));
    }

    $actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

    if($wpb_all_query->have_posts()) :

        while($wpb_all_query->have_posts()) :

            if(isset($postmonth)) {
                $prevmonth = $postmonth;
            }

            $wpb_all_query->the_post();
            $current_ID = get_the_ID();
            $postday = get_the_date('d', $current_ID);
            $postmonth = get_the_date('M', $current_ID);
            $postyear = get_the_date('Y', $current_ID);
            $postcontent = get_the_content($current_ID);

            if($postmonth == 'Jan') {
                $postmonthnumber = 1;
            }
            if($postmonth == 'Feb') {
                $postmonthnumber = 2;
            }
            if($postmonth == 'Mar') {
                $postmonthnumber = 3;
            }
            if($postmonth == 'Apr') {
                $postmonthnumber = 4;
            }
            if($postmonth == 'May') {
                $postmonthnumber = 5;
            }
            if($postmonth == 'Jun') {
                $postmonthnumber = 6;
            }
            if($postmonth == 'Jul') {
                $postmonthnumber = 7;
            }
            if($postmonth == 'Aug') {
                $postmonthnumber = 8;
            }
            if($postmonth == 'Sep') {
                $postmonthnumber = 9;
            }
            if($postmonth == 'Oct') {
                $postmonthnumber = 10;
            }
            if($postmonth == 'Nov') {
                $postmonthnumber = 11;
            }
            if($postmonth == 'Dec') {
                $postmonthnumber = 12;
            }

            if($postmonthnumber < 10) {
                $postmonthnumber = "0" . "$postmonthnumber";
            }

            $fulldateofpost = "$postyear" . "-" . "$postmonthnumber" . "-" . "$postday";

            echo "<div class='tax-calendar-container container'><div class='row'>";

            echo "

                <script>

                    $( document ).ready(function() {

                        $('#" . $fulldateofpost . "').addClass('active');

                    });

                </script>

            ";

            if(isset($prevmonth)) {

                if($prevmonth == $postmonth) {

                } else {
                    echo "
                          <div class='col-2'>"
                        . build_calendar($postmonthnumber, $postyear) . "
                          </div>";
                }

            } else {
                echo "
                      <div class='col-2'>"
                    . build_calendar($postmonthnumber, $postyear) . "
                      </div>";
            }

            echo "
                    <div class='col-10'>
                    <div class='calendar-date'>
                      <span class='day-month'> $postmonth $postday</span>
                      <br>

                      <br>
                      $postcontent
                      <br><br>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                    ";

            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";

        endwhile;
    else :
        _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.');
    endif;

}

add_shortcode('taxCalendarList', 'taxCalendar');
```

Comment: What you want here is a basic _control break_. Compare the month of the current record to that of the previous one - if they are different, you want to close the current container element, and open a new one. (First opening and last closing tag belong before and after the loop then of course.)

Comment: Yes indeed I was comparing the previous with the current to see when to introduce the calendar on the left. Can you write me an example of what you mean above?

Comment: Wrong order - you need to set the current month as the previous one at the end of the loop, after you are done with everything else, not right away at the very beginning. Initialize it with a start value that will not occur in the actual data before the loop, like -1 for example. (You will also need to check whether you are not handling the very first record, so that you don’t output a closing tag/opening tag combination before you output the first row of data already - you can also use that initial -1 value for that.)

Comment: (And get rid of that nonsense dozen of IFs, please … the date format specifier `n` would get you the month number right away, and if you need it with leading zeros, there’s `m` for that.)